# EOCD not found, not Zip,shows error when install apk

Tags: android, apk, adb

When I am trying to install apk through command prompt it shows an error like this

```
daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037
daemon started successfully
EOCD not found, not Zip
file 'com.directv.dvrscheduler_v2.1.1.apk' is not a valid zip file
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/com.directv.dvrscheduler_v2.1.1.apk, No such file
or directory
```

help me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when problem in downloading apk. You may transfer apk statically or storage device, and try again, Hope it will help you. I faced this problem, after transferring apk on skype, i solved my issue.